# Сортировка результатов AJAX-поиска

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет.

Делали на сайте AJAX-поиск по товарам. Столкнулись с такой проблемой, что вводя короткое слово (например, ель), которое встречается в названиях других товаров, то сначала выводятся другие товары, а уже потом только "Ели". Поиск делали по этому [уроку](https://blog-about.ru/blog/ajax-poisk-dlya-wordpress/)

**Для наглядности ситуации.**
Есть ли возможность сначала выводить товары с полным совпадением в начале товара, а уже все остальные?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как происходит выборка у нас сейчас.**

```
$arg = array(
        'post_type' => array('product'),
        'orderby'=> array('type'=>'DESC', 'title'=>'ASC'),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'product_cat' => $category,
        's' => convert_english_letters($_POST['s']),
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_stock_status',
                'value' => 'instock'
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: поиск должен происходить по точному совпадению и только по названию товаров?

Comment: @DarthKYL Поиск только по названиям товаров. 
**На примере.** 
Мы вбиваем "ель" и должны получить сначала все товары "Ель...", а потом все остальные товары у которых в названии где-то есть "...ель...".
Первое слово всегда обозначает вид растения, возможно можно как-то от этого отталкиваться

Answer (score 1):

вам нужно использовать фильтры запроса [posts_where](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/posts_where) для изменения условия поиска только по заголовку и [posts_orderby](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/posts_orderby) для изменения условия сортировки.

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'change_search_query', 10, 2 );

function change_search_query( $where, $query ){
    global $wpdb;

    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query && $query->is_search ) {
        $where = " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_title LIKE '%{$wpdb->esc_like( $query->get( 's' ) ) }%'";
    }

    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'change_order_by_query', 10, 2 );

function change_order_by_query( $orderby, $query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() &&  $query->is_search ) {
        $orderby = " CASE WHEN {$wpdb->posts}.post_title = '{$query->get( 's' )}' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC";
    }


    return $orderby;
}
```